# How to reduce the spacing above and below math symbols?

Tags: spacing, symbols

How to reduce the spacing above and below mathematical symbols like `\sum` ?
For example, typing

```
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^n \text{ where } a_n 
     = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - a)^{n+1}}\, d\xi
```

on my TeX distribution (MiKTeX) renders as :

[image]

whereas the same code on MathML looks like :

[image]

The space above and below the `\sum` symbol (first picture) is rather ugly ^^
Is there a way to reduce it through `\renewcommand`, or some package?
(By the way, it is possible to stretch the `\infty` symbol in order to make it more "condensed" as in the second picture ?)

Comment: On a `displaymath` environment

Comment: The whitespace is still here :(

Comment: If you use `-` or `|` instead of `\infty`, you see that LaTeX is using the baseline instead of the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appendix G "Generating Boxes from Formulas" from "The TeXbook" of Donald E. Knuth specifies the formulas for the spacing between the math operator and the superscript and the subscript:

Space between math operator and superscript: max(ξ₉, ξ₁₁ - depth(superscript))

Space between math operator and subscript: max((ξ₁₀, ξ₁₂ - height(subscript))

The first parameter ξ₉ or ξ₁₀ ensures that there is a minimal distance.
The second parameter ξ₁₁ or ξ₁₂ sets the distance for the baseline of the superscript or subscript; this allows for an alignment of the indices unless the depth/height of the index is too large.

ξₙ is the nth font dimen parameter of the third math font; depending on the current math style the math font is `\textfont3`, `\scriptfont3` or `\scriptscriptfont3`.

The following example uses the normal settings of TeX, then the parameters are set to zero to show a minimized distance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{$\relax$}% trigger math font setup
\typeout{xi_9: \the\fontdimen9\textfont3}
\typeout{xi_11: \the\fontdimen11\textfont3}
\typeout{xi_10: \the\fontdimen10\textfont3}
\typeout{xi_12: \the\fontdimen12\textfont3}
\[\sum_{n=0}^{m} \sum_{n}^{g}\]
\fontdimen9\textfont3=0pt
\fontdimen11\textfont3=0pt
\fontdimen10\textfont3=0pt
\fontdimen12\textfont3=0pt
\[\sum_{n=0}^{m} \sum_{n}^{g}\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

- If there are several operators in the same line, then the second parameters
  should not be decreased too much to avoid an ugly misalignment of the indices.
- The first parameter should not be too small to avoid that the indices are touching the operator (depends on the used fonts and operator glyphs).